# CollapsingToolbarLayout won't collapse

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having issues with the expected scroll behavior of a collapsing toolbar layout within an app. To ensure I kinda knew what I was doing I created a simple test project and was able to achieve the desired result, but a `NestedScrollView` was used in that example and the content that required scrolling was just a `RelativeLayout` containing a `CardView` with a lot of text. In the *real* app the scroll content is a `RecyclerView`, which I assume is the problem. It is as if the RecyclerView is handling the scrolling and the parent CollapsingToolbar is left out of the loop.

Notice that the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` is not currently in the layout. I have tried adding it to various places without the desired result.

Attached is an image of the app after a small amount of scrolling has been performed with the collapsing toolbar above not reducing it's height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.ArticleListActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/theme_primary"
            app:contentScrim="@color/theme_primary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/empty_detail"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: try add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to recyclerview as well/

Comment: @AliHasanzade I tried that, but it results in the RecyclerView shifting way to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code what's missing is that you have to set the scrolling flag "scroll" to the imageview above the Toolbar.
I've done a similar thing and as you can see on the code below, all the views that are meant to react to the RecyclerView Scrolling have the scrolling flag and they are before the views that we don't want to scroll such asthe Toolbar:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            >

            <include layout="@layout/movie_details_header_layout" android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
                android:navigationContentDescription="Back"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The project came using version 22.x of the compat libraries, updating to 23 seemed to fix everything.